# Android Emulator is showing Network Errors, but iOS Simulator works fine

Tags: android, expo, react-navigation, apollo

I've never used Android Studio or an Android Emulator before. Recently I download and set them up on my computer to test a project that I am working on using Expo, React Native, and Apollo graphql. When I test my project on an iOS simulator, I have no problem loging-in or moving between screens. However, when I try to log into my app on the android emulator I am getting an error on the device saying invalid credentials and an error in the terminal saying:

```
{
  "name": "ApolloError",
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "clientErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "line": 21252,
    "column": 33,
    "sourceURL": "..."
  },
  "message": "Network request failed",
  "line": 142425,
  "column": 30,
  "sourceURL": "..."
}
```

To get around this, I tried to create a new user, but I'm getting errors when I do that as well.

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
 LOG  [Network error]: TypeError: Network request failed
 LOG  true
 LOG  {
  "name": "ApolloError",
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "clientErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "line": 21252,
    "column": 33,
    "sourceURL": "..."
  },
  "message": "Network request failed",
  "line": 142425,
  "column": 30,
  "sourceURL": "..."
}
```

In the emulator, it is showing this error in `useNavigation.tsx`, which is a document I don't have in my project. (I might have when I first started it, but I'm not 100% sure) Does anyone know why this might be happening? I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thank you!

Comment: If it is working on ios and not android and failing with network error then make sure you emulator is connected with internet . Network Configuration file is also required to set in android . can you add more details like emulator OS which you are using . Also try to check on real device once

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani I checked the emulator, and I'm able to search the emulator's google chrome app and access the internet, so I don't think that is the problem. In terms of the iOS simulator that I'm using, it is from xcode and it is an iphone 12 running on iOS 14.5. I don't have an android phone, so I can't test it on a physical android device, but when I try to log-in on my iphone using the QR code, I get an error saying that I have invalid credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is having this problem, I was getting this error because  I hadn't changed the `uri` and `url` from localhost to my ip address in my client.ts document (sets up apollo client).
`"http://${IP address}:${PORT}/graphql"`
You have to make this change for the android emulator to work. The iOS Simulator on the other hand, works fine with localhost. I wish the documents had been more clear on this from the beginning it would have saved me a lot of time.

Additionally, some minor issues that I was having after changing localhost to my ip address dealt with `justifyContent`, `alignContent`, etc. I'm used to css, which allows `justify-content:left`, etc., so even though I realized these styling error weren't doing anything in iOS they weren't causing errors, so I had left a couple of them. In android, these errors will cause your app to crash, so it's important to be cognizant of that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing permission in AndroidManifest.xml. Try adding this permission in the manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```